# Generating a report as Table in Splunk

Tags: splunk

I am new to very new to splunk. I need to generate a report in tabular format which has data as below.

```
ClientIP | URL | Count
```

The csv file which I have uploaded contains logs as follows -

```
127.0.0.1 - [25/Nov/2019:07:57:04 +0000] 7792:5011 CF-WRK: 874900139 : 17 "DELETE https://Test123:5011/resources/1012 ?-" 200 - 325240
127.0.0.1 - [25/Nov/2019:07:57:04 +0000] 7792:5011 CF-WRK: 874900139 : 19 "GET https://Test123:5011/resources/697 ?-" 200 580 151807
127.0.0.1 - [25/Nov/2019:07:57:05 +0000] 7792:5011 CF-WRK: 874900139 : 6 "GET https://Demo123:5011/resources ?-" 200 1927 152770
127.0.0.1 - [25/Nov/2019:07:57:06 +0000] 7792:5011 CF-WRK: 874900139 : 3 "GET https://Demo123:5011/resources/ ?-" 200 775 98234
```

What I want to achieve is to group similar URL together along with client ip and show their count.
So far I was able to list URL along with their count using this command

```
sourcetype=access*  [search sourcetype=access*   | top URL | table URL]| stats count AS "Count" BY URL
```

Can someone please hep me here.

Comment: What do you mean by "similar URL"?  The subsearch in your query adds no value.  The `top` command implies you only care about the 10 most common URLs.  Is that true?

Answer (score 0):

As RichG said, its a bit unclear as to what you are trying to do. Some of the following may be suitable.

If you want a count of the number of times every client goes to each URL, you can use the following.

```
sourcetype=access | stats count by ClientIP, URL
```

If instead, you just want a count of the number of unique client IPs with each URL, and the total count of all hits on a URL, you can try this.

```
sourcetype=access | stats dc(ClientIP),count by URL
```